# Not able to get JSON/JSONP properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, api

I'm experimenting/trying to learn how to interact with APIs and am stuck at square one. I'm trying to pull data from the Fever Public API to get a list of subscribed RSS feeds. The API seems pretty simple - http://feedafever.com/api.

I'm able to get data out using the widget provided there, but when I try to write my own code that lets me store the data with Javascript everything falls down - I can't seem to get the response from the server.

I started a JSFiddle with my code at http://jsfiddle.net/WZHKA/. I just want the JSON object to be returned for now and I can go from there. The function is below for convenience too.

(It's got temp login details cause I thought they'd be needed - RSS isn't that private anyway)

Any help would be amazing! I'm stuck, this seems to be what all the tutorials say to do.

Thanks!

```
function buildAPI() {

// FEVER INSTALLATION CONFIG
var url     = 'fever.tommaitland.net/fever';
var email   = 'tommaitland@me.com';
var pass    = 'testpassword';
var args    = 'groups&feeds';
var pargs   = '';
var format = '';

if (!url.match(/^https?:\/\//)) url = 'http://' + url;
if (!url.match(/\/$/)) url += '/';

//var format = $$('format').checked ? '=xml' : '';

var api_key = MD5(email+':'+pass);
pargs = 'api_key=' + api_key + '&' + pargs;

url += '?api' + format +'&' + args;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: pargs,
    success: function(data) {
        document.write(data);
    },
    dataType:'jsonp'
});

return false; 

};

$(document).ready( function() {
buildAPI();
});
```

Comment: That API is JSON not JSONP, [SOP](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) ETC...

Comment: Still doesn't work when I change the dataType to JSON though. I get this error in Console:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://fever.tommaitland.net/fever/?api&groups&feeds. Origin http://www.tommaitland.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: When I use JSONP that error doesn't come up, instead I get a response of `{"api_version":3,"auth":0}` in somewhere in Sources and `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/json: "http://fever.tommaitland.net/fever/?api&groups&feeds&callback=jQuery18303845656830817461_1357358209101&api_key=f50c3a96b5db5de7dcc5ce94f54542df&&_=1357358209113". jquery.js:8322
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ` in Console.

Comment: Its a server side api not client side, you cant use it with AJAX.

Comment: Tom: did you read the pages Musa linked to?

Comment: But JSON is a client side format? Should I be interacting with it with PHP?

Comment: @nnnnnn : Yeah I did, they wen't over my head. Can I send those headers with my code? I thought the block was on the installation's side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think there is something wrong with the setting of feedafever's api server. I pessimistically think the only way you can interact with the api is using iframe, which the test widget does. Let me explain the reason.

first of all, the api server doesn't set it's response header to accept cross domain access. they should do something like

```
response.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
```

on the server side to accept cross domain access. As they didn't do it, you have to use jsonp to avoid the `not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` issue.

However, the api server should respond a "real" jsonp when the request asks jsonp as response data type, which means they should do something on the server side like

```
response.set_header("Content-Type", "text/javascript")
```

and wrap the json (let's say it's `{"foo":"bar"}`) with a javascript tag

```
JSONP({"foo":"bar"}) // the name JSONP is not fixed, you can name it whatever you like
```

jQuery will add `callback=JSONP` as parameter in the url and execute `JSONP` as ajax call back automatically. NOTICE: as JSONP is provided as javascript function, it only works with http `GET`.

In your case, feedafever set their content type as `text/json` while Chrome expects script, so you got the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` error.

In short, it's not your fault. The only option you can use this api properly is iframe.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it in such depth, I really appreciate it. I thought it might be something like that. The thing that gets me though is that other apps (iPhone apps) use the API to access this same installation. Do you think these problems would be avoided if I used the XML output instead of JSON?

Comment: I am not familiar with XML, but I think the answer is no. Because it's a problem about cross domain, not about data type. have a look: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/getting-xml-data-from-cross-domain

Comment: Yeah you were right - gave it a shot, no luck. I've emailed the developer about it to see if he has any further information. In the meantime I'll see if I can extract data out of the iframe, which feels like a massive hack. Will update the thread when I find a solution!

Comment: Good luck man :)  Besides, I found I was a bit misunderstanding JSONP. I have updated it, please have my updated answer a look.